# What should I use Dependency Injection or Binding in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

I have the class UserRepository

```php
class UserRepository
{
    public function getUsersByCompany(Company $company)
    {
    }
}
```

For use this class in the controller I use Dependency Injection

```php
class UserController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function index(Company $company)
    {
        retrurn $this->repository->getUsersByCompany($company);
    }
}
```

Also, I can use Binding

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function boot()
   {
   }
   public function register()
   {
         $this->app->singleton('user-repository', function ($app) {
               return $this->app->make(UserRepository::class);
         });
   }
}
```

```php
class UserController extends Controller {

   public function index(Company $company)
   {
       retrurn app('user-repository')->getUsersByCompany($company);
   }
}
```

I do not understand which way is better? What should I give priority to?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `$this->app->singleton` this will create only one instance of the repository and use it other places where you do `app('user-repository')` instead of creating a new object. If you don't have some complex dependencies for the repository, I would stick to `__construct(UserRepository $repository)` in the controller. This is used to automatically resolve any dependencies which are simple enough for Laravel to figure on itself, e.g. class names, not interfaces. Since your repository doesn't depend on anything else you could also do

```
(new UserRepository())->getUsersByCompany($company);
```